# windows application & service installer

Tags: c#, .net

i have a solution that contains 2 projects:
1-windows application project.
2-windows service project.
may you help me to create an installer that install both of them using VS2010, as the registry keys should also be created in the registry during setup.
Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a few options for creating an installer: [Wix](http://wixtoolset.org/), [Inno](http://www.jrsoftware.org/isinfo.php), [InstallShield](http://www.installshield.com/). All of them can help you with installing your project as a service and add keys to the registry.

InstallShield is a bit more capable, but it is not free. I heard good things about Wix, but never had a chance to use it. Inno is my tool of choice. It sometimes can be fiddly, but once you have learned all the cotchas, it is a breeze.